# How to get the reference while using `if let` optional unwrapping (swift)

Tags: swift, if-statement, reference

I'm trying to inject some values inside the `[String: Any]` for later use.

**Minimalistic example of my code:**

```
var info = ["Person" : [
  "Age" : 20,
  "Name" : "Ratul Sharker"
]]

print(info)

if var person = info["Person"] as? [String:Any] {
  person["height"] = 5.5
  print("~~> Height injected")

  //
  //  however if i reassign the
  //  person into the info, then 
  //  the info appear into the print
  // info["Person"] = person
}
print(info)
```

The code is also shared [here](https://repl.it/repls/PeruJumpyAdministrator)

**Output of this code gives me**

```
["Person": ["Age": 20, "Name": "Ratul Sharker"]]
~~> Height injected
["Person": ["Age": 20, "Name": "Ratul Sharker"]]
```

Clearly the `height` i am injecting has no effect, because when the optional unwrapping is happening it creates another copy of the `person` dictionary. So the change remains the local. Assigning the local person into the dictionary do the trick.

Here what i want is not copying the value while optional unwrapping using `if let`. Is there any way that i can tell `if let` construction so that it take the reference of the value instead of value. I have searched a lot about this scenario, all i get the pass by reference to a function using `&` and `inout`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not print info, print person. And read about value types.

Comment: The real problem here is the modelling of your data as a weakly typed `[String: Any]` dictionary, rather than a custom model type. If you define a couple of strongly typed `struct`s to represent your data instead, your problem will disappear as you'll just be able to say `info.person.height = 5.5`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the new dictionary `person` back into the original one.

```
if var person = info["Person"] {
    person["height"] = 5.5
    info["Person"] = person // <------ important
}
```

### Update

Since you don't want to use the optional binding statement, here's another solution

```
struct Person {
    let age: Int
    let name: String
    var height: Float?
}

var person = Person(age: 20, name: "Ratul Sharker", height: nil)

person.height = 5.5
```

Comment: Please check the comment's of my code, i've already done that, but it isn't stop copying of data. Here `if var person` person is just another copy of the `info["person"]`

Comment: OP has already written same code in comment but he don't want to achieve this way.

Comment: I understand, but i want to use optional binding which gives reference instead of newly copied object. Here Person isn't the only entity i wanted to modify, there are numerous. I want to fill the missing entries before `Decoding` them using `Codable`. The api which responds the resulted json is now missing some key-values, which i need to fill out based upon some condition.

Comment: @RatulSharker `Dictionary` in Swift is a **Value Type**. If you want to use the Optional Binding statement then you need to accept that a copy will be done. But I don't understand why this is a problem for you. Are you concerned about app performance?

Answer (score 1):

It is like you wrote, a **dictionary** is a **value-type**. So if you want to make changes, you have to do it on the origin var (in your case it is `info`).

this means to do it like the following:

`info["Person"]?["height"] = 5.5`

Comment: `info["Person"]?["height"] = 5.5`

Comment: Yes i understand, but the example given here is very simplified version of my wanting. I have to check for availability of the `Person` before injecting the values @Sandu

Comment: ich you only want to check die availability you could make it like `let _ = info["Person"] as? [String:Any] { }`. @RatulSharker

Comment: This is the same thing as copying into another person object without taking any reference to the copied object. Which produces another copy of the same person which i don't want.

Comment: By using *optional chaining*, `info["Person"]?["height"] = 5.5` will assign `5.5` to `height` if `Person` exists, otherwise it safely does nothing.

Comment: I think that for your approach the solution from @vacawama is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

you code is giving error of `error: downcast from '[String : Any]?' to '[String : Any]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?
if var person = info["Person"] as? [String:Any] {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~`

because in this info["person"] is also returning an optional you and you are wrapping it again

```
var info = ["Person" : [
"Age" : 20,
"Name" : "Ratul Sharker"
]]

print(info)

if var person = info["Person"] {
person["height"] = 5.5
info["Person"] = person
print("~~> Height injected")

//
//  however if i reassign the
//  person into the info, then
//  the info appear into the print
// info["Person"] = person
}
print(info)
```

and for the other question why your dictionary is not changing is because in optional binding when value is unwrap it is copied in another variable and you changing copy of it just assign that copy to your variable and you are done!!

Answer (score 0):

The change doesn’t get saved in your info variable because this line:

```
if var person = info["Person"] as? [String:Any]
```

is creating a new variable (person) and you only inject the height value into that variable.

To save it to your info object you could do this:

```
info[“person”] = person
```

Or

```
info[“person”][“height”] = 5.5
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: If you want to check for the person first then do this:

```
if var person = info[“person”] as? [String: Any]
{
    person[“height”] = 5.5
    self.info[“person”] = person    //saves the injected person to info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is so similar with Matrix in arrays

> note that if you had a dictionary in another dictionary you must treat each dictionary as a variable

```
var parentDictionary : [String:Any] = ["Developer":["iOS":"Swift"]]

print(parentDictionary["Developer"]) 

// log -> ["iOS":"Swift"]

print(parentDictionary["Developer"]["iOS"]) 

// log -> "Swift"
```

now in your case if you need to check if person had value like dictionry

```
if var person = info["Person"] as? [String:Any] {
  print("\(person.values)")
 // log -> [20, "Ratul Sharker", 5.5]
}
```

but it's not the way you want to add params to your dictionary